# In C#, why does using a field vs. an auto-implemented property cause different behavior in this case?

Tags: c#, syntax, properties

Take the following code from http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx:

```
using System;

struct MutableStruct
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public void SetValue(int newValue)
    {
        Value = newValue;
    }
}

class MutableStructHolder
{
    public MutableStruct Field;
    public MutableStruct Property { get; set; }
}

class Test
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MutableStructHolder holder = new MutableStructHolder();
        holder.Field.SetValue(10);
        holder.Property.SetValue(10);

        Console.WriteLine(holder.Field.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(holder.Property.Value);
    }
}
```

(There were a couple of comments in the code I missed earlier or didn't read that I've taken out now.)

The claim on the article is that the output is `10` for `holder.Field`, but `0` for `holder.Property`, and this has been verified to be accurate.  I'm having a bit of trouble seeing why though.  An auto-implemented property will have one specific field set aside that it's mapped to, and due to being a struct, `Property` will immediately have had its backing field fully set and constructed from the beginning.  What's the difference?

Comment: You already have the differences, you've written them down in the comments. You're mutating the value in the field but you are obtaining a copy from the property and mutating the copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `holder.Property` returns a copy of `MutableStruct`. So when you write `holder.Property.SetValue(10)` you are changing the copy, not the original.

The line `holder.Field` is an alias for the `MutableStruct` itself.

It is really hard to not accidentally make copies of structs. Thus we try to not make them mutable.

Comment: P.S. In my 14+ years of working with .NET, I can only recall making one mutable struct in a production application. And that's because I wanted myArray.ToArray() to make a copy of each element.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is the interjection of a getter for the property.  It's functionally equivalent to

```
private MutableStruct _Property;
public MutableStruct GetProperty()
{
    return _Property;
}
public void SetProperty(MutableStruct value)
{
    _Property = value;
}
```

So when you call

```
holder.Field.SetValue(10);
```

you are mutating the struct at `Field` *directly*, but when you call

```
holder.Property.SetValue(10);
```

you are mutating the *copy* of the struct returned from `GetProperty`.

Comment: if you look at the IL properties are actually compiled as methods `X get_Property()` and `void set_Property(X value)` ... but your point is the same :)

Comment: @MatthewWhited That's why I said _functionally_ equivalent.  The compiler-generated names are irrelevant.